# Batch Launcher With Variables

Tags: script, batch, vbscript

This batch launcher was created so that batch files won't launch a command prompt window... Now that i'm adding more variables to it, it's not working...

I'm launching the VBScript like so;

**wscript D:\batchlaunchersyntax.vbs D:\the batch\batch.bat 11 D:\program files\hello world**

The last 2 variables change. I would like to launch the batch file passing a number followed by a directory variable.

Can you please help me edit this VBScript in order to do that?

```
'--------------------8<----------------------
sTitle = "Batch launcher"

Set oArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

If oArgs.Count <> **3** Then

```
' Will die after 10 seconds if no one is pressing the OK button
oShell.Popup "Error: You need to supply a file path " _
& "as input parameter!", 10, sTitle, vbCritical + vbSystemModal

Wscript.Quit 1
End If

sFilePath = oArgs(0)
sArg = oArgs(1)
```

**sArg2 = oArgs(2)**

```
If Not oFSO.FileExists(sFilePath) Then
' Will die after 10 seconds if no one is pressing the OK button
oShell.Popup "Error: Batch file not found", _
10, sTitle, vbCritical + vbSystemModal

Wscript.Quit 1
End If

' add quotes around the path in case of spaces
```

iRC = oShell.Run("""" & sFilePath & """" & **sArg & " " & sArg2 & " "**, 0, True)

```
' Return with the same errorlevel as the batch file had
Wscript.Quit iRC

'--------------------8<----------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Read and follow [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html):

> **Using "Double Quotes"**
>
> If a single parameter contains spaces, you can still pass it as one
>   item by surrounding in "quotes" - this works well for long filenames.

Applied to your case, use:

```
wscript D:\batchlaunchersyntax.vbs "D:\the batch\batch.bat" 11 "D:\program files\hello world"
```

Otherwise, the command line is tokenized as follows:

```
rem     ↓ script name
wscript D:\batchlaunchersyntax.vbs D:\the batch\batch.bat 11 D:\program files\hello world
rem oArgs(0)    D:\the
rem oArgs(1)    batch\batch.bat
rem oArgs(2)    11
rem oArgs(3)    D:\program
rem oArgs(4)    files\hello
rem oArgs(5)    world
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script only accepts two arguments, so you would have to change this line to reflect the number of arguments you want to pass to the script:

```
If oArgs.Count <> 2 Then
```

Change the 2 to whatever your new limit will be.

The first argument, `oArgs(0)`, is the name of the batch script you want to run.

The second argument, `oArgs(1)`, is the name of the parameter to pass to the first argument.

In order to pass more arguments, you must assign `oArgs(2)` and so on to new variables, and then change the line that reads:

```
oShell.Run("""" & sFilePath & """" & sArg, 0, True)
```

...so that more arguments can be passed to the script. You would add those after the `sArg` variable, thusly: `sArg & " " & sArg2 & " " & sArg3` assuming you assigned the passed arguments to `sArg2` and `sArg3`

Of course, your batch file must know what to do with the passed arguments. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I implemented the changes but I still get: **Error: You need to supply a file path as input parameter!** when running _wscript D:\batchlaunchersyntax.vbs D:\the batch\batch.bat 11 D:\program files\hello world_

Comment: The order of parameters is important, and it's 0-based index. So, oArgs(0) is the name of the batch file, 1 is the path the batch file is expecting, 2 would be your numeric value. Change your batch logic accordingly.